# Is it possible to run a script when a build is pinned in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity

In Teamcity it is possible to pin builds. Does anybody know if it is possible at all to have "Pin Actions"?

I have tried to find information about it in the JetBrains TeamCity documentation but until now not able to come up with a solution.

The underlying problem is that we want to tag our SVN repository only for pinned builds, not just for succesful builds.

I'm using TeamCity 6.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-9578) for pin build trigger, but it's not already resolved. JetBrains offers to use [URL trigger plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/Url+Build+Trigger), but it may be difficult if there is no guests support in your teamcity.

Also your can write [custom build trigger](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Custom+Build+Trigger), it would be very useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will look into it to see if any of the given options works for me. At first it looks like you focus on build triggers. The thing is that I don't want another build to be triggered but a completly custom action to be performed.

Comment: I tried to make it work by using the Url trigger but rain into this problem now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295688/teamcity-plugin-urltrigger-keeps-firing

Answer (score 4):

Actually as this topic is first on Google search...

This functionality is already present: Add trigger -> Schedule trigger -> Show advanced options -> Trigger only if watched build changes -> Last pinned build

As you can configure scheduled build to check it every minute or even more often that will work exactly as intended.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you. The question is over 3 years old and is based on TC 6.5. In Version 7 it was still not possible. Now with version 9 it is indeed possible to select pinned builds.

Comment: @amaters yep, but your question is still popular on google (I came here searching if it is possible but followed to the issue provided in the answer). :) I've suggested edit to the original answer but not sure it will be approved.

Comment: I hope not since the question is regarding version 6.5. Although your answer i appreciated