# TeamCity plugin UrlTrigger keeps firing

Tags: plugins, teamcity, teamcity-7.1

I have setup the trigger to listen to the last pinned build artifacts:

```
<TEAMCITY URL>/repository/downloadAll/bt79/.lastPinned
```

However, the trigger keeps firing every 30 seconds which is the default Polling interval.

Am I missing something here? The url always gives me the same file.

UPDATE:
After upgrading to TeamCity 7.1 the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question came from TeamCity support:

> The reason of the described behaviour is the way TeamCity controller
>   returns data requested in downloadAll query. The .zip containing the
>   artifacts is actually different on each request and build is
>   triggered.
>   To workaround this issue try using

```
<TEAMCITY URL>/guestAuth/repository/download/bt79/.lastPinned/<some artifact> if possible.
```

this one worked for me.